# how to make java JFR to include the timestamp in the file on dump StartFlightRecording filename with timestamp

Tags: java, jfr

I am starting the flight recording in this way :

```
java -XX:StartFlightRecording=dumponexit=true,filename=/path/to/recorders/myrecording.jfr
```

I would like to have the file named with the timestamp of the moment of the dump, lets say I dump next day using jcmd, I would like the name something like **/path/to/recorders/2021_09_14_myrecording.jfr**

I have tried reading documentation I have not found anything useful.
I might create a separate script that renames the file appending the timestamp using bash, but before wanted to ask here if there is any built-in feature in java to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running JDK 11-17, you can specify only the directory, and a filename with timestamp and pid will be generated, for example "hotspot-pid-7066-id-1-2021_09_15_15_56_03.jfr"

```
java -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=/path/to/recordings/ ...
```

There is no need to specify dumponexit=true if you set a filename.

The timestamp will be generated when the dump happens.

Comment: It does not appear that the documentation says anything about the filename pointing to a directory.  Is this based on experience or have you found it documented somewhere?

Comment: You can do "jcmd 0 help JFR.start"

  filename        (Optional) Name of the file to which the flight recording data is
                  written when the recording is stopped. If no filename is given, a
                  filename is generated from the PID and the current date and is
                  placed in the directory where the process was started. The
                  filename may also be a directory in which case, the filename is
                  generated from the PID and the current date in the specified
                  directory. (STRING, no default value)

Comment: Yes, that's what the documentation says.  You said that "you can specify only the directory" and I have not seen _that_ documented anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr004.html you have also the option "repository" instead of "filename"

```
XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,repository=/tmp,maxage=6h,settings=default
```

This means you need to change filename to repository.
I have tried it and it works very nice

It will generate a filename as mentioned before with  hotspot-pid-1-id-1-2024_02_14_16_35_12.jfr as an example

Comment: The repository is the temporary directory where the JVM writes data. It is deleted when the JVM exits. 

The filename points to the places where the JVM concatenates (smaller) files in the repository and writes it to a single dump file.

Comment: Yes Kire, you are right. But I didn't mention why I think that is a better approach: Under CICD you only have the pipeline start up time, therefore you need to use automatic naming for the black box moment, when there is a restart on the pod, which relates to the break down timing. That's why I suggest using a dynamic file name templating, and save it under a known directory. Otherwise the pod will save internally the flight recording, and you need to specify the path properly and set it up in a external storage for later access.